# Ansible task make block with throttle

Tags: ansible, roles

I want to use throttle for the playbook execute task on server one by one. unfortunately ansible gave me error

> ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.   mapping values are not
> allowed in this context

```
  - hosts: server
        tasks:
          - name: Block of tasks with throttle
            throttle: 1
            block:
              - name: ---
                ----
    
              - name: ---
                ----
```

I think, because it is a task from a role and I cannot add task again.
I have worked with only a task and call him directly, but I want to work on a role

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an indentation issue. Make sure that the `tasks:` property is on the same level as `hosts:` :

```
  - hosts: server
    tasks:
      - name: Block of tasks with throttle
        throttle: 1
        block:
          - name: ---
            ----
    
          - name: ---
            ----
```